# Implementing a find-and-replace procedure in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Just for fun, I'm trying to write a find-and-replace procedure like word processors have. I was wondering whether someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong (I'm getting a `Timeout` error) and could help me write a more elegant procedure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void find_and_replace(std::string& text, const std::string& fword, const std::string& rword)
{
     for (std::string::iterator it(text.begin()), offend(text.end()); it != offend;)
     {
        if (*it != ' ')
        {
           std::string::iterator wordstart(it);
           std::string thisword;
           while (*(it+1) != ' ' && (it+1) != offend)
                thisword.push_back(*++it);   
           if (thisword == fword)
               text.replace(wordstart, it, rword);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }

     }   
}

int main()
{
    std::string S("Yo, dawg, I heard you like ...");
    std::string f("dawg");
    std::string w("dog");
    // Replace every instance of the word "dawg" with "dog":
    find_and_replace(S, f, w);
    std::cout << S;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::find_if`? and then use the iterator returned to replace?

Comment: There are a couple of problems, but ... where are you getting a `Timeout` error from?

Answer (score 1):

A find-and-replace like most editors have would involve regular
expressions.  If all you're looking for is for literal
replacements, the function you need is `std::search`, to find
the text to be replaced, and `std::string::replace`, to do the
actual replacement.  The only real issue you'll face:
`std::string::replace` can invalidate your iterators.  You could
always start the search at the beginning of the string, but this
could lead to endless looping, if the replacement text contained
the search string (e.g. something like `s/vector/std::vector/`).
You should convert the the iterator returned from `std::search`
to an offset into the string *before* doing the replace (`offset
= iter - str.begin()`), and convert it back to an iterator after
(`iter = str.begin() + offset + replacement.size()`).  (The 
addition of `replacement.size()` is to avoid rescanning the text
you just inserted, which can lead to an infinite loop, for the
same reasons as presented above.)

Answer (score 1):

- using `text.replace` may invalidate any iterators into text (ie, both `it` and `offend`): this isn't safe
- copying each character into a temporary string (which is created and destroyed every time you start a new word) is wasteful

The simplest thing that could possibly work is to:

1. use `find` to find the first matching substring: it returns a `position` which won't be invalidated when you replace substrings
2. check whether:

   1. your substring is either at the start of the text, or preceded by a word separator
   2. your substring is either at the end of the text, or succeeded by a word separator
3. if 2.1 and 2.2 are true, replace the substring
4. if you replaced it, increase `position` (from 1) by the length of your replacement string
5. otherwise increase `position` by the length of the string you searched for
6. repeat from 1, this time starting your find from `position` (from 4/5)

end when step 1 returns position `std::string::npos`.

Answer (score 0):

1) you don't push first symbol of found word into "thisword" variable.

2) You use only space symbol ' ' as separator, and what about comma ','. Your program will find word "dawg," not "dawd"

The following code works, but you should think about other word separators. Do you really need to replace only whole word, or just sequence of symbols?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void find_and_replace(std::string& text, const std::string& fword, const std::string& rword)
{
     for (std::string::iterator it(text.begin()), offend(text.end()); it != offend;)
     {
        if (*it != ' ' && *it != ',')
        {
           std::string::iterator wordstart(it);
           std::string thisword;
           while ((it) != offend && *(it) != ' ' && *(it) != ',')
                thisword.push_back(*it++);   
           if (thisword == fword)
               text.replace(wordstart, it, rword);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }

     }   
}

int main()
{
    std::string S("Yo, dawg, I heard you like ...");
    std::string f("dawg");
    std::string w("dog");
    // Replace every instance of the word "dawg" with "dog":
    find_and_replace(S, f, w);
    std::cout << S;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do word separators have to do with find-and-replace?  He's barking up the wrong tree with searching for word separators.

Comment: I don't know why word separators are needed, but the program replaces words separated by spaces, not just sequences of symbols. I just fixed errors in current implementation.